# How to specify import for Live Template with Kotlin extension function in Intellij

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea, live-templates

I'm using the following Live Template:

```
timber.log.Timber.debug { "$METHOD_NAME$" }
```

where `debug` is an extension function:

```
package timber.log
inline fun Timber.debug(throwable: Throwable? = null, message: () -> String) {
  log(DEBUG, throwable, message)
}
```

Intellij adds `import timber.log.Timber` automatically.
Is it possible to specify the import also for `timber.log.debug` in Intellij/Android Studio?

Comment: [Margarita Bobova](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12994157) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68668533) saying "Seems like type aliases is what you need [https://kotlinlang.org/docs/type-aliases.html](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/type-aliases.html), [https://medium.com/@erickpranata/kotlin-import-alias-3f2831295902](https://medium.com/@erickpranata/kotlin-import-alias-3f2831295902)"